# Context for .launchUrl in outsourced helper class

Tags: java, android

I have some problem with the context in the methode launchUrl in an outsourced class. I use the Chrome Custom Tabs from several classes in my application and I will use one methode for all Custom Tabs Intents.

Here my Helper:

```
public void openCustemTab(String url, Context context) {
    CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
    builder.setToolbarColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    builder.setShowTitle(true);

    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
    customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(url));
}
```

And this is call in my Activity/Fragment:

```
Helper helper = new Helper();
                    helper.openCustemTab("Some URL", getApplicationContext());
```

My problem is, that the context in methode openCustomTab for the .launchUrl dosen't work. Have someone an idea for my problem?

Comment: Doesn't work is not an error. An error is It does X but I expected Y where X might be a helpful error message, stack trace, or odd output.

Answer (score 0):

It's because launchUrl parameters are Activity (not Context) and Uri. As you can see it here: [void launchUrl (Activity context, Uri url)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.html#launchUrl(android.app.Activity,%20android.net.Uri))

You can replace:

```
 customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(url));
```

with

```
 customTabsIntent.intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
 context.startActivity(customTabsIntent.intent, customTabsIntent.startAnimationBundle);
```